# Flexible columns in Hubspot Email Template

Tags: hubspot

While developing an email template in Hubspot, I stumbled upon a problem with flexible content columns. I wanted the user to be able to drag and drop modules into the email template just like standard website page templates. But upon saving I get the message: 'You cannot include a widget container in an email template.'
Is there an alternative approach for making a modular, flexible email template? Or should I make a bunch of different template with different layouts? Hopefully not...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use flexible columns in emails, unfortunately.

http://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/cos-general/how-do-flexible-columns-work

Answer (score 1):

Its not a proper way to use Flexible module on Hubspot, its already mentioned by HS, same in case of adding style sheet also

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those of you looking for a "flexible solution" I created an email template that uses a custom block module that lets you create as many models as you need. Also, if you decide you want to rearrange them you can drag and drop them into the order. So this functionality makes things flexible but works within the constraints of table based HTML emails.

Would appreciate any feedback you have: https://marketplace.hubspot.com/products/bootstrapcreative/aqueduct-card-email

[image]

Thanks,

Jacob